# The problem is when the program executes the else, when the password and username is true. Any Ideas about it?

Tags: java

1. Initializes an array to store three instances of the following:

Firstname
Lastname
Username
Password

2. When the program executes:

2.1. Asks for a user‟s username and password

2.2. Implements a looping statement which validates the given username and password three

times maximum and performs either of the following:
A. If the username and password did not match/either of the two is incorrect/ both incorrect,

prompt a message: “The username and/or password is invalid. Please try again” Allow

three attempts and terminate the program when the third attempt fails.

B. If the username and password matched, prompt the following:

B1. Welcome (full name of the user)

```
int A = 3; boolean B = false;

     String[] FirstName = {"ken", "Ikuma" , "Denzel Baron"};
     String[] LastName = {"kaneki", " Kabaneri" , " C. Quitain"};
     String[] name = {"Haisesasaki", "Denzel43", "Baronbarz"};
     String[] pass = {"haise4231", "denzel4231", "baronbarz4231"};
    do{    
     System.out.println("Enter username");
     String username = you.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter password");
     String password = you.nextLine();

     if(username.equals(name[0]) && password.equals(pass[0])) 
     {        
         System.out.println("Welcome user " + FirstName[0] + "" + LastName[0]); 
         B = true;
     }
     if(username.equals(name[1]) && password.equals(pass[1]))
     {
         System.out.println("Welsome user " + FirstName[1] + "" + LastName[1]);
         B = true;
     }
     if(username.equals(name[2]) && password.equals(pass[2]))
     {
        System.out.println("Welcome user " + FirstName[2] + "" + LastName[2]);
        B = true;
     } 

     else if(!username.equals(name[0]) && !password.equals(pass[0]) 
         && (!username.equals(name[1]) && !password.equals(pass[1]) 
         && (!username.equals(name[2]) && !password.equals(pass[2]))) && A > 1)
     {
         System.out.println("try again");
     }       
     else 
     {        
     System.out.println("no more tries");    
     }
     A--;
    } while ( A > 0 && B == false);
```

Comment: You could just `break` the loop if one of the combination matches

Comment: I wonder why a question like "any ideas about it" gets *only* an upvote :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the change...

```
  else if(!(username.equals(name[0]) && password.equals(pass[0]) )


            && !(username.equals(name[1]) && password.equals(pass[1]) )
             && !(username.equals(name[2]) && password.equals(pass[2]))) 

&& A>=1)



         {
             A=A-1;
             System.out.println("try again");
         }
```

and 
use else if instead of if (apart from 1st if).

(As your **else** combines with last **else if** which combines with last **if**. so if 1st statement is correct then also other **if** will be tried .. and when it will return false then **elseif** and then else.)

Comment: Yup, you're correct but the problem is that when the user type the correct string and say "Welcome user" and the else statement execute too it shouldn't be executed when the username and password is correct.

Comment: ok. update the above.

Comment: Now I know, it really help me